# What type of encoded text is this and how can I translate it?

Tags: encryption, encoding

I have no experience, but I've been playing a game and it's rather interesting.  One of the character files has a long line of scrambled text and I was wondering if someone could tell me if it's cipher and if you could nudge me in the right direction of solving it. [Here's](https://pastebin.com/9eA8bxDh) a pastebin link, but if you don't want to open it I'll put a few lines of it here:

```
SWYgeW91IGZvdW5kIHRoaXMgbm90ZSBpbiBhIHNtYWxsIHdvb2RlbiBib3ggd2l0aCBhIGhlYXJ0IG9uIGl0LCB0aGV
uICpjb25ncmF0dWxhdGlvbnMhKiBZb3UgYXJlIHByb2JhYmx5IHRoZSBmaXJzdCBwZXJzb24gdG8gcmVhZCB0aGlzLi
BJIGRpZG7igJl0IHJlYWxseSBwbGFuIG9uIHNoYXJpbmcgdGhpcyB3aXRoIGFueWJvZHksIGJ1dCBmb3Igc29tZSByZ
WFzb24gSSB0aGluayBpdOKAmXMgZXhjaXRpbmcgdGhhdCBzb21lYm9keSBvdXQgdGhlcmUsIGEgY29tcGxldGUgc3Ry
YW5nZXIsIHdpbGwgY29tZSBhY3Jvc3MgdGhpcyBub3RlIGFuZCByZWFkIG15IHN0b3J5LiBTb21lb25lIEkgd2lsbCB
uZXZlciBtZWV0LCBzaGFyaW5nIHN1Y2ggYSBwZXJzb25hbCBib25
```

Comment: This is a base64 encoded shock story.  It has made it's way around the internet in a few different places and more details on the specific inclusion in the game is discussed on the steam forums [here](http://steamcommunity.com/app/698780/discussions/0/3182216552774421743/).  Posted as a comment since this is off topic here and I didn't want people voting for it as an answer.  Posting so that those who do decode it know what's up.

Answer (score 2):

Since this looked like Base64 encoding, I opened the first online encoder/decoder tool from Google (https://www.base64decode.org/) and inputed your string. After decoding, got this result:

> If you found this note in a small wooden box with a heart on it, then
>   *congratulations!* You are probably the first person to read this. I didn’t really plan on sharing this with anybody, but for some reason I
>   think it’s exciting that somebody out there, a complete stranger, will
>   come across this note and read my story. Someone I will never meet,
>   sharing such a personal bon

As said, this is encoding, not encryption. Both of the techniques obfuscate clear text but the purpose of encoding is to protect the message from bad parsing, meanwhile the purpose of encryption is to hide it from someone who is not supposed to read it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your information was helpful and I thank you it, if there's any beginners guide could I get it?  This topic is interesting and I'm curious on the subjects of encoding and encryption.